# Google not enlisting our root page

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, sitemap, homepage

The structure of our angularjs site is like

```
/
/main
/page1
...
/page9
```

where `/` is redirecting to `/main`. So we have 10 pages and Google lists 10 pages like

```
www.ourpage
ourpage/page1
...
ourpage/page9
```

We're redirecting away the `www` prefix, so `www.ourpage` redirects to `ourpage/main`. Listing the former in the search results makes more sense and *so far, everything looks good.*

We're also providing a `sitemap.xml` containing our 10 pages. On the page https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list, Google shows that 10 pages were submitted, but only 9 were indexed. I doubt it's a real problem, but I'd like to get some insight as others believe it could be a problem. The non-counted page is most probably the root page. I've tried three variants, each of them containing the 9 "normal" pages and one of

- `ourpage/main`
- `ourpage/`
- `www.ourpage/`

and resubmitted the sitemap, but nothing has changed. We always get 9 indexed out of 10.

Note that there's nothing wrong with our pages, especially the root page scores 97/100 in https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights and there are no issues.

- May this be a real problem?
- Can we solve it without providing replacing `/main` by `/`?

Comment: Google doesn't index pages that redirect and you shouldn't put URLs that redirect in  your sitemap.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller But putting the target page in the sitemap doesn't work either.

Comment: What type of redirect are you using?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm using 302 (so it doesn't get cached; Google doesn't complain about it). Details: The URL gets normalized by 1. switching to HTTPS, 2. removing `www.`, 3. replacing `/` by `/main`.; all three steps done at once (no redirect chain).

Answer (score 1):

Google follows the 301, 302, 306, 307 commands as expected. Such intermediate pages are not considered useful, though, and thus Google indexes them but does not show you such pages in its results. It makes more sense to send users directly to the destination, don't you think? This, of course, means that changing the main page once in a while will take a little time to get updated at Google (i.e. if you `/main` were to become `/home`.)

Now, it would be best if you could avoid that `/main` altogether and use `/` instead. "Just" display the contents of `/main` when users go to `/` and if you change that to `/home` later, Google will still point to your home page anyway! (since you'd be showing the contents of `/home` when a user is accessing `/`.)

Note that Google is likely to check your home page (`/`) once in a while either way. That way they can make sure that the redirection did not change. Actually, I have many 404 generated by Google for pages that I have removed so long ago I cannot even remember... They recheck any page that existed at some point in time, they are likely to check `/` out over and over again. If it "Re-appears" they are not unlikely to re-add it to their index fairly quickly.

So in other words, you're fine, but it could be a bit better. If that main page path is unlikely to change, or will change very rarely, then I wouldn't worry about it.